# Adding to a list in a bean from my JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I new to jsp's so pls bear with me.

I create a bean with a list in it.

```
public class ListBean {

List<Question> questions;

public void addquestion(Question question) {
    this.questions.add(vraag);
    }

public List<Question > getQuestions() {
    return questions;
}

public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
    this.questions= questions;
}
}
```

Is there a possibilty to add to this list in this bean from my jsp?

```
<jsp:useBean id="listbean"
    class="be.beans.ListBean" scope="page"></jsp:useBean>
```

I only know `<jsp:setProperty ...` but that will not work.

Comment: Why do you want to add something to a list in a JSP? JSP is the view layer; non-view functionality belongs in Java code.

Comment: @DaveNewton Agreed.  The questions are a elementcollection in my JPA entity and I whas thinking of dynamicly adding them on my jsp page before adding the whole element (entity) through my repostory to the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been quite some time since I worked with JSP. Im not sure whether it is possible with taglibs, but with scriptlets (java code in jsp), yes its possible.

```
<% ListBean listBean = pageContext.getAttribute("listbean");
   listBean.getQuestions().add(question);
%>
```

`question` in above snippet is a `Question` object that you wanted to add to the list.

Comment: Agreed.  But I would try to avoid scriptlets in my jsp.  If possible off course

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exact  from you, as my knowledge you need to use that `list` for `entire application` and store it in `database` , if that so i refer the following snippet

```
<jsp:setProperty name="list" property="listbean">
      <jsp:attribute name="value">
         <%=ListBean.questions%>
      </jsp:attribute>
</jsp:setProperty>
```

`import ListBean` class in `jsp page`

you can use this property `listbean` for entire application and possible to store to `database` from any further pages